# How to download the reply to a html form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a web page with a form like this

```
<form id="merge" method="get" action="/idmu/merge">
    <ul>
        <li><label for="fullname">Full Name</label><input name="Full Name"  id="fullname"/></li>
        <li><label for="shortname">Short Name</label><input name="Short Name" id="shortname"/></li>
    </ul>
    <p><button type="submit" form="merge" download>Download Draft</button></p>
</form>
```

The response provided by the server on submit is a XML document, and I need to download that document rather than displaying it in the browser. A traditional download link like

```
<a href="/idmu/merge" download="mydoc.xml">Download</a>
```

does not do a "submit" with the values from the input fields. Cross browser support is important, Safari and IE seem to be an extra challenge for this.

Comment: What's the code behind `/idmu/merge`?

Comment: A java servlet that returns an xml document with an http content type of text/plain.

Comment: `text/plain`? That's a lie. It should be `application/xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell the client that the HTTP response is an [attachment](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) with a Content-Disposition response header.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="example.xml"'
```

Comment: Is this css markup? If so, what element should it apply to, the button or the form?

Comment: No, it is an HTTP response header.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the client side without that disposition?

Comment: Err… make the whole thing dependant on JavaScript, do the entire request via Ajax, get the content into a string, convert it in a data: scheme URI, lie about the content-type. But that would be awful. The content-disposition is the standard way to say an HTTP resource should be downloaded instead of being opened inline and has been for almost two decades. It is simple, standard, and well supported.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to specify the file name from the client rather than in the http header?

Comment: No. Either it comes from the URL or it comes from the filename parameter to the content-disposition header.